# Why can I no longer access wifi networks?

Tags: wireless

I have been accessing wifi for 2 1/2 weeks all over Mexico. Suddenly, I cannot connect. Nothing has changed except my geographic location. (Unless I did something inadvertent on my over-sensitive keyboard-is that possible?) Help!

Comment: Any recent updates ? does it work with an older kernel ? does it work on another OS (dual boot windows)?

Answer (score 2):

Try going to system settings and select Network then wireless, make sure that Airplane mode is OFF and that Wireless is ON